# unable to display image using mpdf......instead of image it displays a cross sign

Tags: mpdf

```
$pdfFilePath = "Agreement.pdf";

$this->load->library('M_pdf');

$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I")
```

Comment: Show your HTML, nothing we can do not knowing what your HTML looks like.

Comment: <td><center>7</center></td>
 <td><img src="<?echo $agree_photo[0]['link']?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>

Comment: above is the html code.......image gets displayed in html page but when converting it into pdf it shows cross sign.

Comment: and the actual content of `$agree_photo[0]['link']` variable?

Comment: actual content is that in ['link'] there is an link of a JPG file

Comment: What is the link!? Is it a relative link, absolute filesystem link, URL, or what?

Comment: It's an URL....

Comment: i have added $mpdf->debug = true;
        $mpdf->showImageErrors = true; as well still its not working